# Always use default e-mail instead of user's e-mail - Human translation services - E-mail translation

Tags: internationalization, kentico

Is there a way (web.config flag?) to override the "Human translation services - E-mail translation" *from address* to use a SMTP Server user and password, or to use the default SMTP server instead of trying to send an e-mail as the current user?

E.g. scenario:

- Assume user is using a working SMTP server definition -- server, user and password defined in Settings -> System -> Emails -> Default SMTP Server section
- Each Kentico user is not setup to send e-mails as themselves
- Kentico Admin has an option to specify "Default e-mail sender", but can't specify the SMTP info (server, username, password), can only set the e-mail address. Kentico overrides this e-mail address if the user has an e-mail in their profile
  ** Question: Is there a way to always use this e-mail, regardless of requesting user's (translation requestor) email/profile settings?

Thanks,

Victor

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to override this behavior on the email template level? Check [this](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Human+translation+services+-+Email+translation#Humantranslationservices-Emailtranslation-Customizingthetranslationemails).